# how to add @ at the first byte of the line after matching line pattern

Tags: linux

I need help from expert on this. How can I add @ at the first byte of the line after found matching pattern. For example as below :

Input:

```
TESTING
1234
0001
0002
0003
```

Output:

```
TESTING
@1234
0001
0002
0003
```

Comment: Add more tags related to your Code/Project so that you may get more quick and exact answers. as Tags help questions to be more specified/Categorized

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the matching pattern? This seems like it should be easy to do with perl, awk, or sed. Find the pattern line, go to the next line, and do `s/^/@/` to insert `@` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may execute the following sed script on the file:

`sed -n '/TESTING/{p;n;s/^/@/;};p;' file`

- `-n` - don't print output on default
- `/TESTING/` - if TESTING is matched
- `{` - then
- `p;` - print output, 'TESTING'
- `n;` - read next line, the line after TESTING
- `s/^/@/` - substitude beginning of the line wiht @
- `};`
- `p;` - print output. This will print all non-matched lines with TESTING or will print the next line after TESTING witch substituted '@'